# How to load an executable in Scheme using the command line

Tags: scheme, racket

I am using DrRacket and produced a file, `hello.scm` in emacs with the following content:

```
 #! /usr/bin/env racket


                ;The first program

 (begin
   (display "Hello, World!")
   (newline))
```

I then tried to compile the file at the terminal by using `le$ racket hello.scm`, and received this result:

```
  Le-MacBook-Pro:~le$ racket hello.scm
default-load-handler: expected a `module' declaration, but found
 something else
 file: /Users/le/hello.scm
 context...:
 default-load-handler
 standard-module-name-resolver
 module-path-index-resolve
 [repeats 1 more time]
 module-declared?
```

Moreover, when I copy and paste the content of the emacs file into DrRacket and click `Run`, I receive the following message:

```
Module Language: only a module expression is allowed, either
    #lang <language-name>
 or
    (module <name> <language> ...)
 in: (begin (display "Hello, World!") (newline))

Interactions disabled.
```

What exactly is the problem?

Comment: you missed one more edit....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding `#lang racket` at the top of the emacs file.